# Convert from probability scale to logit scale in R?

Tags: r

I want to convert values on the probability scale to the logit scale. For example, if I create some probabilities, I could convert them like so:

```
# Create some probabilitws between 0 and 1
probs <- round(runif(5, 0.0, 1.0), 2)

# convert to logit
prob_logit <- function(x) {
  out <- log(x / (1 - x))
  return(out)
}

prob_logit(probs)
```

The issue is, if the probability is either 0 or 1, then my function will return either `-Inf` or `Inf` as the logit will approach ± infinity. So, my question is, how do I convert from the probability scale to the logit scale, whilst also taking into account the presence of a 0 or 1 probability?

Comment: If the probability is either 0 or 1, what's the right corresponding value in logit scale in your opinion.

Comment: -Inf and Inf makes sense...  I guess I could rescale my probabilities to be between almost 0 and almost 1 (e.g. 0.001, 0.999)... but I was wondering if there was some clever way I could deal with these values in R.I need to represent these values on a heatmap and obviously I cant do that with Inf

Comment: Maybe `?qlogis` , it can be calculated if the probabilities are passed on the `log` scale which can provide more stable calculations when your probabilities are almost 0 or 1